# How to specify custom weight updates in tensorflow custom optimizer

Tags: optimization, tensorflow2.0

In a custom optimizer I would like to update weights with random values if the loss function has not decreased.

However, I can not see how to do that in the methods you can override (resource_apply_dense, resource_apply_sparse, create_slots, get_config). None of them are passed the loss function.

I have tried overriding minimize(), but that is not called in a  standard training loop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a custom optimizer, I think the easiest way to apply it is to explicitly define the layers, also. In a standard feedforward neural network, if `x` is the input, then `h=tf.tanh(tf.matmul(x,W)+b)` is an example of the first hidden layer. Similarly you can get more layers. Then W and b are variables you need to update. The training loop would look something like this:

```
trainable_variables=[W,b]
for i in range(1000):
     optimizer.minimize(loss, trainable_variables)
```

but with your own optimizer instead of the one from keras.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response, I was trying to absorb your answer, but not sure I understand it. How does writing custom layers help in adjusting the weights from the custom optimizer? Btw, the link doesn't work.

Comment: I edited a bit further, in my opinion it is much clearer if you have the variables you wish to update written explicitly as matrices. You don't have to overwrite anything from keras then... I understand that you probably do wish to use keras, and I would have left this as a comment, but don't have enough reputation.
The author of the question from the link seems to have erased it, so I removed it.

Comment: Thanks I have done it in a custom loop in a non-keras class, but was hoping to keep it in the keras framework. I'll try with minimize.()